# Поиск конкретного слова на странице с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, поиск, текст

Добрый день. Искал в интернете, примеров много разных поиска слова по странице, но обычно это именно функция поиска для юзера. А мне нужно, чтобы функция работала незаметно для пользователя и при обнаружении или отсутствии искомого текста производила определенные действия.

Comment: что значит _функция поиска для юзера_?

Comment: можно пример показать пожалуйста?

Answer (score 7):

Я предпочитаю в таких ситуациях использовать RexExp:

```js
(function() {
  var text = 'обычно это именно функция', // Текст, который надо найти
      regexp = new RegExp(text, 'i');

  if (regexp.exec(document.getElementById('text').innerHTML)) {
    // Если нашло, то выполнить это
    var reg = new RegExp(text, 'g');
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML.replace(reg, '<span style="color: red">' + text + '</span>');
  } else {
    // Если не нашло, то выполнить это
    console.log('Текст не найдет');
  };
}());
```

```html
<p id="text">Добрый день. Искал в интернете, примеров много разных поиска слова по странице, но обычно это именно функция поиска для юзера. А мне нужно, чтобы функция работала незаметно для пользователя и при обнаружении или отсутствии искомого текста производила определенные действия.</p>
```